# How to reset RTKQuery mutation state back to `uninitiated` inside a thunk?

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I have a [RTKQuery mutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations) for submitting data to server, which uses `fixedCacheKey`. I manipulate it via `.initiate()` function within thunks:

```js
dispatch(
  commentsApi.endpoints.updateComment.initiate(
    { commentId, patch },
    { fixedCacheKey: getFixedCacheKey(commentId) }
  )
)
```

I am looking for a way to programatically reset its state back to `status: "uninitialized"` inside my custom thunk action.

There there is [a "reset" function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations#frequently-used-mutation-hook-return-values) returned by `useMutation` hook, which seems to do exactly what I want - but I want it done inside a thunk - something like:

```js
// This does not work (commentsApi.endpoints.updateComment.reset is not a function)
dispatch(
  commentsApi.endpoints.updateComment.reset({ 
    fixedCacheKey: getFixedCacheKey(commentId) 
  })
)
```

How can I make this reality? :)

Answer (score 1):

That reset is also on the object you get from dispatching `initiate`:

```js
const runningMutation = dispatch(
  commentsApi.endpoints.updateComment.initiate(
    { commentId, patch },
    { fixedCacheKey: getFixedCacheKey(commentId) }
  )
)


// later
runningMutation.reset()
```

you just need to save that variable to the side.

You *can* also use `api.internalActions.removeMutationResult({ requestId })` or `api.internalActions.removeMutationResult({ fixedCacheKey })`, but that is an implementation detail and might change in the future.